# Unable to parse bindings for optionsText

Tags: knockout.js

I am not sure why I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: data is not defined;
>   Bindings value: options: dateOptionsArray,optionsText: data,value: data knockout-2.2.1.debug.js:1936
>   ko.utils.extend.parseBindingsString

for this model:

```
function ViewModel(jsonModel) {

    var self = this;
    self.dateOptionsArray = ["YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"]; //todo make this dynamic
```

in this html:

```
 <select id="f" data-bind="options: dateOptionsArray,optionsText: data,value: data"></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to have a property named `data` on order to the `value` binding work:

```
function ViewModel(jsonModel) {

    var self = this;
    self.dateOptionsArray = ["YYYY-MM-DD", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"];
    self.data = ko.observable();

};
```

Second don't need to the `optionsText`. You only need it when you have complex objects in your array and you want to specify which property KO should use for the select text. See also in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

```
<select id="f" data-bind="options: dateOptionsArray, value: data"></select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mv4G9/)

Comment: Why it seems reduntant? You need a property (in this case `data`) for holding the selected value from the `value` binding: `value: data`

Comment: ah cool, so if I done this:  self.data = ko.observable("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"); then the correct option would be selected?

Comment: Yes, exactly KO does two way bindings.

Comment: so there must be some code that selects the option in the background :)